# Mailboxusage report via Graph api gives back hash values

Tags: azure, graph, azure-active-directory, exchange-server, microsoft-graph-mail

We are trying to get a mailboxusage report from Microsoft Graph API.
We are using an azure app registration with application permission Users.Read.All; Reports.Read.All; User.Export.All
We also tried those permission as delegated permission.

The report gives the userprincipalname and display name back as hash values like this

B9AEDADB26B6539164C2F9DD6 (not a real one)

[image: Output example]

Are we missing an api permission ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, I too got **same results** as you with hash values when I tried to fetch mailbox usage report via Graph API like this:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getMailboxUsageDetail(period='D7')
```

**Response:**

[image]

> This happens when your tenant is configured to **hide** user information for all reports.

To **resolve** the issue, modify below setting by logging into Microsoft 365 Admin Center as **Global Administrator**:

*Go to the  [Microsoft 365 admin center](https://admin.microsoft.com/) -> Settings -> Org Settings ->  Services -> Select  **Reports** -> Uncheck this option* -> Save

[image]

When I ran the same Graph API call again now, I got the **results** with User principal name and display name successfully like this:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getMailboxUsageDetail(period='D7')
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[Microsoft 365 reports show anonymous instead of actual user names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/microsoft-365/troubleshoot/miscellaneous/reports-show-anonymous-user-name)